# Kubuntu transfer to new root disk

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, boot-repair

My Kubuntu 16.04 root disk was on a 120 GB SSD partitioned with GPT. I cloned this disk to a 512 GB SSD using CloneZilla. The new disk will not boot. I loaded Kubuntu 16.04 live and tried boot-repair on the new disk (`/dev/sdd`), but I received this message:

> GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

The disk `/dev/sdd` has an unnumbered partition from 0 - 2048 MB (which I assume to be the BIOS-Boot partition??) then SDD1 (the `/` partition) then sdd2 (the swap partition). `/dev/sdd1` has flags boot, esp. But I can't figure out how to create the BIOS-Boot partition and run boot-repair successfully.

Instructions appreciated.